# How to set up environment variable properly?

Tags: 12.04, environment-variables

I opened the `/etc/environment` and added the line `ANDROID_SDK_HOME="/home/tom/android-sdk"`  but I tried `echo $ANDROID_SDK_HOME` but displayed nothing. I have `JAVA_HOME` in the same `/etc/environment` but its working. Please help me fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing the file never gets opened yet. Run `source /etc/environment` from a command line and `echo` the variable again.

Comment: I'm happy I helped. TheKoju's answer is a more permanent fix -- accept that one.

Comment: Isn't the main difference that ``/etc/environment`` is system wide and ``/home/nobody/.profile`` is specific to the user ``nobody``? Both should be persistent / permanent. Both approaches have their place

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Environment variables can be defined permanently by editing the `.profile` file in your home directory. Here's how:

Edit your `.profile` file with a command like `gedit ~/.profile`. Append this to the end of the file:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/tom/android-sdk
```

You can `source .profile` to make it apply right away. Each time you restart your system, the `.profile` file is loaded, restoring this setting.

Answer (score 9):

Its not recommended to use `.profile` file anymore to store *user specific environment variables*.

Use `~/.pam_environment` file instead.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables